# Can't select an existing column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in SQL and I'm trying to select column Foto_municipis:

```
    askdbase4=# select * from avatar_avatarx;
 id | llista_municipis | Foto_municipis  | primary |     date_uploaded      
----+------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------
  1 | Tore             | tore.jpg        | t       | 2014-06-05 01:19:40+02
  2 | Calldetenes      | calldetenes.jpg | f       | 2014-06-05 23:24:18+02
  3 | Rupit i Pruit    | baixa.jpeg      | f       | 2014-06-16 03:09:48+02
  4 | Olost            | olost.jpg       | f       | 2014-06-16 23:20:05+02
(4 rows)
```

for some reason I can select llista municipis successfully:

```
SELECT llista_municipis FROM avatar_avatarx;
```

but when I try to select Foto_municipis this is what I get:

```
askdbase4=# SELECT llista_municipis FROM avatar_avatarx;

ERROR:  column "Foto_municipis" does not exist
LINE 1: select Foto_municipis from avatar_avatarx;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is all explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: looks like according to the manual the sign of a name needing quotes is if it contains a char not the in the set {[a-z], [0-9], _, &}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably created the column with a double-quoted identifier and this will work:

```
select "Foto_municipis"
from avatar_avatarx
```

That is almost always a bad idea as it will be forever necessary to reference it using double-quotes, unless it is an all lower case identifier in which case it can be referenced in lower case without double quotes.

If the column is created with an identifier without double quotes then it is possible to reference it in any case style like `Foto_municipis` or `foto_Municipis` regardless of the original identifier case style.